# What's the difference between home_url() and get_home_url() from a developmental point of view?

Tags: home-url

Both functions return the website url.

And, as home_url() needs sanitization (for example `<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>)`, why it is this snippet of code, instead of `<?php echo get_ home_url( '/' ); ?>`, that we found in Wordpress Codex and Wordpress Template Twenty Nineteen ?

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. I hope you find the answer(s) you are looking for. Our site is different from most - if you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work.

Comment: Thanks. I will check your tour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't much difference but they are **not** the same.

#### get_home_url

`get_home_url()` takes null or a blog id as the first parameter. As per documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_home_url/).

> get_home_url( int $blog_id = null, string $path = '', string|null $scheme = null )

If you are dealing with multiple homes (as in, say a multi-site set up) this might be useful.

### home_url

`home_url()`, on the other hand, is less fussed about per blog settings and just wants the home URL. As per documentation [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/home_url/).

> home_url( string $path = '', string|null $scheme = null )

It is the equivalent of calling `get_home_url( null, $path, $scheme );`. Most of the time, this is the function you want.

Comment: If i understand you well, as `get_home_url()` is taking this blog id as a parameter, it makes more sense for a standard wordpress template as Twenty Nineteen to use it in the header.php, cause it could be used in a multisite set up, which is relevant because it's pretty common. Thanks a lot for your very clear and pedagogic answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference. If you look at wordpress code you will see

```php
function home_url( $path = '', $scheme = null ) {
        return get_home_url( null, $path, $scheme );
}
```

Comment: Welcome to [wordpress.se]. If you have not done so yet, consider checking out the [tour](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help center](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how things work. Check the [guide to answers](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for further advice on giving comprehensive answers.